# Sitecore RTE not showing HTML editor tab

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor, richtext

Using Sitecore 10.0.1
I updated the HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile in sitecore config as below so as to use bullet points and numbered lists.

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text IDE" />
```

But after this change not able to see the design tab/ html tab as below
[image]

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the profile `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text IDE` does not contain the item `HTML View` in the `Buttons` folder. You can check it by switching to the **core** database and exploring different profiles under the tree `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/`.

If you want to include Design/HTML tabs in the Rich Text IDE profile, you can copy the `HTML View` item from another profile, for instance Rich Text Default or Rich Text Full:
[image: HTML view item]

Alternatively, if you plan to make other customisations to the Rich Text Editor profile, consider creating a custom profile and modifying it as per your requirements.